# How convert Mysql datetime format "2015-10-10 10:30:59.108000" to User readable format Like "Oct. 10, 2015, 2:31 p.m"

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, django-models

6, python 2.7 with MYSQL database.

Following are the details

**settings.py**

```
#Mysql database connection
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'monitoringtool',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

**Models.py**

```
class MonitoringDetail(models.Model):
    host_id = models.ForeignKey('HostDetail')
    transac_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)    
    def __unicode__(self): 
        return '%s %s %s'% (self.id, self.host_id, self.transac_date)
```

**views.py**

```
date_objects = MonitoringDetail.objects.all()
for date_object in date_objects:
            transac_date = date_object.transac_date
            print transac_date
```

In the above view when I print transac_date it gives me to date in this format: `2015-10-10 08:38:25.299000+00:00`
But actually I want to date in this format: `Oct. 10, 2015, 2:31 p.m`.

Please help me here I am not sure where I am missing?

Comment: Hmmm, we disagree on what "user-readable" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django `DateTimeField` is normalized to a python datetime and you can use the methods provided by the library to format your date. The date you see is the default one. Here is the link to the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime

For your case you need:
`print transac_date.strftime('%b. %d, %Y, %I:%m %p')`

Comment: Thanks @Bogdan for your reply it helps.I got the expected format. But still I am facing issue with time zone, it is not giving me the local time zone for India.  I also tried changing the TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'.

Comment: Timezones are a bit tricky. You should install `pytz` and follow the instructions here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/